# How can I access my Mac OSX home folder on my macbook?

Tags: permissions, mac, macbook, macosx

First of all, I'm not under ubuntu, but Pear OS 7, (quantal based).
I have a macbook pro 5,5 (late 2009) with an SSD where there are the OSX and Pear OS partitions, and an HDD where I store my OSX home folder (disk named "data").
I tried to follow [this guide](http://mac.linux.be/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=95) to be able to access my osx documents, but I'm still not able to do that.
when I access the "data" partition clicking on the icon on Files file manager, then check the folders permission, I see that almost all of them are owned by user id 99 and group dialout (the same group of which I changed the ID following the guide).
Checking on the mac side, folders are owned by the right user and group, uid=501 and gid=20.
is there something I can do to solve this?
thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that using UID=99 and GID= 99 solved any problems.
That's strange, but it's working for now (I'm using read only access, just to listen to my music and copy my work files).
Now I have a lot of system users on gdm login screen, but since I'm using autologin it's not a big problem.